# Replace XML Array with new Array using System.Xml

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I am trying to replace a node in my XML file, but I need some help resolving how to replace a Node with a non-unique name or identifier.
The Question is, How do I replace to following Node with Data from XmlDataReplace:

```
/Document/ExclusionContainer/Mobile_Devices
```

Below is some sample code and data used in the sample code.

**Sample Code**

```
private void ReplaceXmlArray()
{
 System.Xml.XmlDocument OriginalXmlDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
 //Scroll Down for XmlData     
 OriginalXmlDoc.LoadXml("StackOverflow - XmlDataOriginal");      
 string NewXmlContent = "StackOverFlow - XmlDataReplace";

 //Need help here on Code to Replace
 //Node in OriginalXmlDoc
}
```

**XmlDataOriginal** - Original Doc

```
<Document>

 <DefaultContainer>

  <Mobile_Devices>
   <Mobile_Device>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <Name>Device-One</Name>
   </Mobile_Device>
  </Mobile_Devices>

 </DefaultContainer> 

 <ExlusionContainer>

  <Mobile_Devices>
   <Mobile_Device>
    <Id>2</Id>
    <Name>Device-Two</Name>
   </Mobile_Device>
  </Mobile_Devices>

  <Laptops />

 </ExclusionContainer>

</Document>
```

**XmlDataReplace** - Will Replace Data in XmlData1 (Document/ExclusionContainer/)

```
<Mobile_Devices>
   <Mobile_Device>
    <Id>2</Id>
    <Name>Device-Two</Name>
   </Mobile_Device>
   <Mobile_Device>
    <Id>3</Id>
    <Name>Device-Three</Name>
   </Mobile_Device>
</Mobile_Devices>
```

Comment: It's very unclear what you're asking, to be honest - you haven't shown any code to even *try* doing a replacement, nor is it clear in what way `/Document/ExclusionContainer/Mobile_Devices` identifies more than one node...

Comment: The question is "How do I replace /Document/ExclusionContainer/Mobile_Devices with the data from 'XmlDataReplace' ". I tried to do it but I am having problems collecting the right Node

Comment: So what have you *tried* in terms of finding the right node? It seems that the replacement part is pretty irrelevant at the moment - your question is really about finding it. Personally I'd strongly recommend using LINQ to XML rather than XmlDocument - that will make it even easier than it already is with XmlDocument.

Comment: Yes, I agree it might be more about finding it. So far the method OriginalXmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName keeps giving me exceptions but I will look into the Linq to Xml. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got your point.
Correct me if i am wrong :- 
You want to update(replace or create) the  data.
Lets do this way
I choose these two xmls

Orignal.xml stored in c:\data\orignal.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Document>
  <DefaultContainer>
    <Mobile_Devices>
      <Mobile_Device>
        <Id>1</Id>
        <Name>Device-One</Name>
      </Mobile_Device>
    </Mobile_Devices>
  </DefaultContainer>
  <ExlusionContainer>
    <Mobile_Devices>
      <Mobile_Device>
        <Id>2</Id>
        <Name>Device-Two</Name>
      </Mobile_Device>
    </Mobile_Devices>
  </ExlusionContainer>
</Document>
```

the second replace.xml stored in c:\data\replace.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ExclusionContainer>
  <Mobile_Devices>
    <Mobile_Device>
      <Id>2</Id>
      <Name>Device-Two</Name>
    </Mobile_Device>
  </Mobile_Devices>
  <Mobile_Devices>
    <Mobile_Device>
      <Id>3</Id>
      <Name>Device-Three</Name>
    </Mobile_Device>
  </Mobile_Devices>
  <Laptops />
  </ExclusionContainer>
```

Copy paste the below code

```
     XmlDocument originalDoc = new XmlDocument();
        originalDoc.Load("c:\\data\\Orignal.xml");
        XmlNode exclusionNode = originalDoc.SelectSingleNode("/Document/ExlusionContainer");

        XmlDocument docToReplace = new XmlDocument();
        docToReplace.Load("c:\\data\\replace.xml");

        XmlNode replaceNode = docToReplace.SelectSingleNode("/ExclusionContainer");
        exclusionNode.InnerXml = replaceNode.InnerXml;
        originalDoc.Save("c:\\data\\orignal.xml");
```

Comment: This indeed does the job. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = 

                "<Document>" +
                  "<DefaultContainer>" +
                    "<Mobile_Devices>" +
                      "<Mobile_Device>" +
                        "<Id>1</Id>" +
                        "<Name>Device-One</Name>" +
                      "</Mobile_Device>" +
                    "</Mobile_Devices>" +
                  "</DefaultContainer>" +
                  "<ExlusionContainer>" +
                    "<Mobile_Devices>" +
                      "<Mobile_Device>" +
                        "<Id>2</Id>" +
                        "<Name>Device-Two</Name>" +
                      "</Mobile_Device>" +
                    "</Mobile_Devices>" +
                    "<Laptops />" +
                  "</ExlusionContainer>" +
                "</Document>";

            string newNode = 
                "<Mobile_Device>" +
                    "<Id>3</Id>" +
                    "<Name>Device-Three</Name>" +
                   "</Mobile_Device>";



            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(input);
            XElement newElement = XElement.Parse(newNode);

            XElement exlusionContainer = doc.Descendants("ExlusionContainer").FirstOrDefault();
            XElement mobileDevice = exlusionContainer.Element("Mobile_Devices").Element("Mobile_Device");
            mobileDevice.ReplaceWith(new XElement[] { mobileDevice, newElement });
        }
    }
}
​
```